# How to get euler/quaternion rotation from matrix?

Tags: python, scripting, bones, transforms, matrix

I have 2 bones and I want to copy the rotation of one bone to another
using **only** `rotation_quaternion` or `rotation_euler` to assign the rotation

something like this:

```
Bone1 = armature.pose.bones["Bone1"]
Bone2 = armature.pose.bones["Bone2"]

Bone1_loc, Bone1_rot, Bone1_scale = Bone1.matrix.decompose()

orig_rot_mat = Bone1_rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()

Bone2.rotation_quaternion = orig_rot_mat.to_quaternion() 
#or Bone2.rotation_euler = orig_rot_mat.to_euler()
```

but this doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why

**Note:**
I'm NOT trying to assign rotation using `Bone2.matrix` so please do not post a solution like this:

```
Bone1 = armature.pose.bones["Bone1"]
Bone2 = armature.pose.bones["Bone2"]

Bone1_loc, Bone1_rot, Bone1_scale = Bone1.matrix.decompose()
Bone2_loc, Bone2_rot, Bone2_scale = Bone2.matrix.decompose()

orig_loc_mat = Matrix.Translation(Bone2_loc)
orig_rot_mat = Bone1_rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
orig_scale_mat = Matrix.Scale(Bone2_scale[0],4,(1,0,0)) * Matrix.Scale(Bone2_scale[1],4,(0,1,0)) @ Matrix.Scale(Bone2_scale[2],4,(0,0,1))

# assemble the new matrix
Bone2.matrix = orig_loc_mat  @ orig_rot_mat @ orig_scale_mat
```